# Erro ao realizar uma consulta à base de dados

Tags: php, mysql, zend, sql-select

Estou usando o Zend e tenho a seguinte função:

```php
public function getChamado($id) {
  try {
    $cols = array(
      'id', 'titulo', 'descricao', 'fk_status', 'fk_local',
      'fk_tipo', 'created', 'modified', 'finished', 'fk_usuario',
      'fk_restricao', 'fk_prioridade'
    );

    $sql = $this->getDefaultAdapter()
      ->select()
      ->from($this->_name, $cols)
      ->where('id = ?', $id);

    return $this->fetchRow($sql);

  } catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage(); die;
  }
}
```

Ela me gera esta linda e perfeita consulta:

```sql
SELECT
    `tbl_chamado`.`id`,
    `tbl_chamado`.`titulo`,
    `tbl_chamado`.`descricao`,
    `tbl_chamado`.`fk_status`,
    `tbl_chamado`.`fk_local`,
    `tbl_chamado`.`fk_tipo`,
    `tbl_chamado`.`created`,
    `tbl_chamado`.`modified`,
    `tbl_chamado`.`finished`,
    `tbl_chamado`.`fk_usuario`,
    `tbl_chamado`.`fk_restricao`,
    `tbl_chamado`.`fk_prioridade`
FROM
    `tbl_chamado`
WHERE
    (id = '1')
```

porém ao executar dá o seguinte erro:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

*Todas as variáveis estão corretas, a query gerada é a mesma acima. Executando diretamente no banco ela traz os dados normalmente.*

**Houve algum detalhe que eu deixei passar?**

Comment: Estranho esse erro. Uma pergunta: `id` é varchar?

Comment: `int` e `auto increment`.

Comment: Já tentou converter o `$id` para inteiro, só para ver se gera a query sem as aspas? Eu entendi que a query roda diretamente no banco, mas é só um chute de que o Zend pode tentar fazer alguma mágica e isso acaba prejudicando.

Comment: Antes dessa consulta, você executa outro código junto ao banco?

Comment: Ja tentei isso tmbém @utluiz, não executo mais nada @ricidleiv!

Comment: Você consegue ativar o log do servidor para monitorar as queries? O Zend pode estar concatenando alguma coisa  nessa query antes de enviar para o banco. Sobre o log, veja [este link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-log.html), tavez ajuda.

Answer (score 1):

O parametro $id que você passa é uma String? Se for, faz o seguinte teste.

```
public function getChamado($id) {
try {
$id = (int) $id;
$cols = array(
  'id', 'titulo', 'descricao', 'fk_status', 'fk_local',
  'fk_tipo', 'created', 'modified', 'finished', 'fk_usuario',
  'fk_restricao', 'fk_prioridade'
);

$sql = $this->getDefaultAdapter()
  ->select()
  ->from($this->_name, $cols)
  ->where('id = ?', $id);

return $this->fetchRow($sql);

} catch(Exception $e){
echo $e->getMessage(); die;
}
}
```

Comment: Foi uma das primeiras coisas que tentei, não rolou, mas obrigado...

Answer (score 0):

Tenta com esse código

```
    $sql = $this->getDefaultAdapter()
        ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
        ->select()
        ->from($this->_name, $cols)
        ->where('id = ?', $id);
    return $this->fetchRow($sql);
```

Comment: o `setIntegrityCheck(false)` é pra quando você vai fazer uma consulta com `join` em outras tabelas...de qualquer forma obrigado pela intenção.

Answer (score -1):

Pelo erro tem algo errado na escrita de algum campo ou tabela da Query ou o usuário que você está utilizando não tem permissão para executar essa ação neste banco ou tabela.

Uma dica, tente executar essa query no terminal ou em uma IDE de modelagem de dados como MySQL Workbench (Windows/Linux), NaviCat(Windows/Linux) ou Sequel Pro(OSX).

Comment: Eu rodo ela no NaviCat, e vai de boa...

Comment: Utilizando o mesmo usuário que está sendo utilizado na aplicação ?

Comment: Sim, @devsdmf...